# Help me in building the intution to solve these types of problems.

Tags: probability

A box contains 12 chocolates, 3 of which are white chocolate, 4 milk chocolate, and 5 dark chocolate.

I am sharing the box with three of my friends. The four of us take turns, each one drawing a chocolate at random from those available in the box. Yes, we're drawing without replacement. We intend to eat the chocolates, not put them back.

Politely, I let my friends draw before me.

For each of the subparts, provide your answer as an unsimplified fractional expression.

a) What is the chance that I draw a dark chocolate?

b) What is the chance that the friend who gets to select first draws a dark chocolate and I draw a dark chocolate too?

Comment: Looks like a rephrased homework problem. What have you tried? Show your working.

Comment: There were two more questions. I have solved them. I just reviewed a book. This is the case of simple random sampling, and the probability that I will choose dark chocolate after all my friends will be 5/12 only. For b part, the probability should be 20/132. Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you for your concern.http://stat88.org/textbook/notebooks/Chapter_02/02_Symmetry_in_Simple_Random_Sampling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the following

a) $p=\frac{5}{12} \frac{4}{11} \frac{3}{10} \frac{2}{9}+3\frac{7}{12}\frac{5}{11}\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}+3\frac{7}{12} \frac{6}{11} \frac{5}{10} \frac{4}{9} + \frac{7}{12} \frac{6}{11} \frac{5}{10} \frac{5}{9} \approx 0.42$

The first term accounts for three friends picking dark, the second for two of the three friends picking dark, the third for only one friend picking dark, and the last one for neither of them picking dark.

b) $p=\frac{5}{12}(\frac{4}{11}\frac{3}{10}\frac{2}{9}+2\frac{7}{11}\frac{4}{10}\frac{3}{9}+\frac{7}{11} \frac{6}{10}\frac{4}{9}) \approx 0.15$

Same principle, first term = both of the last two friends pick dark, second = one of the two pick dark, last = none of the two pick dark

Comment: You don't have to multiply all the terms. check this. http://stat88.org/textbook/notebooks/Chapter_02/02_Symmetry_in_Simple_Random_Sampling.html